# float array gives different datas at the end of it in objective c

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I bumped to a strange error.(at least for me) I am trying to use float array in FFT and audio filters that I apply. but float array gives different datas at the end.

I define a global pointer. I point a float array to it. but when I try to use the pointer in somewhere out of the scope of a method, the last 100-150 datas of 441000 datas get mostly 0 or some other very big numbers. I dont understand how a data can change when I use somewhere in out of scope
in scope I loop in it and every data is correct but when I try to loop outside of the scope of the method I created the array, it gives different datas at the end.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    float *filteredData;
    int theFileLengthInFrames;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
..
..
-(void)FilterData:(float * ) rawData
{
    int count = theFileLengthInFrames;

    float filteredRawData[count];
    for (int i  = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        filteredRawData[i] = rawData[i];
        printf("%d_%f ",i,filteredRawData[i]); 
        //I check here to see the data . In here it is normal
    }
    filteredData = filteredRawData;
}

-(void) CalculateFFT
{
    int numSamples = theFileLengthInFrames;
    for (int i = 0; i<numSamples; i++)
    {
        printf("%d_%f ",i,filteredData[i]);  
        //when I check here to see the data , the last around 100 data are 0.00000 or some big number such as 250399682724883753288597504.000000
    }

}
```

need help thanks

Comment: How/where is `filteredRawData` declared ?

Comment: And how is filteredRawData initialized?

Comment: sorry, it was 'anotherRawData' . Here I corrected that

Comment: Something weird going on also.  "float anotherRawData[count];"  count is defined as an int in the same scope - doesn't the array size need to be defined at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FilterData:` method points the instance variable `filteredData` to a local array `filteredRawData`.  Since `filteredRawData` is allocated on the stack, it becomes invalid when `FilterData:` returns.  Then `filteredData` is a dangling pointer, and using it results in undefined behavior.

Solution: allocate persistent storage for `filteredData`.  I would do it like this:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSMutableData *filteredDataStorage;
    float *filteredData;
}

-(void)FilterData:(float * ) rawData {
    int count = theFileLengthInFrames;
    filteredDataStorage = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:count * sizeof *rawData];
    filteredData = (float *)filteredDataStorage.mutableBytes;
    for (int i  = 0; i<count; i++) {
        filteredRaw[i] = rawData[i];
        printf("%d_%f ",i,filteredRawData[i]); 
        //I check here to see the data . In here it is normal
    }
}
```

Using `NSMutableData` for the persistent storage lets ARC take care of deallocating it when you call `FilterData:` again, or when `ViewController` is deallocated.

Comment: is there a badge for simultaneous same answer?  ++rob

Answer (score 2):

filteredData - The float pointer is an ivar, it's scoped to your object instance.

filteredRawData is defined at method scope.  It's an array located on the stack.  When filteredRawData goes out of scope that memory is no longer valid.  Reading from it is undefined at best and could result in an access violation.  You probably want to use malloc to dynamically allocate memory for your data, or have a global buffer defined for you to play with.

Comment: thank you, Now I see my mistake :) . I wish I could pick yours as solution too. Aprreciated